# cannot find symbol - variable whatever

Tags: java

I've recently discovered programming and on the suggestion of a friend decided to try my hand at making my first project a mad lib game. 
I've ran into a rather frustrating 
"cannot find symbol - variable whatever" when i try to compile. 
I've pasted my code below in the hopes that someone can give me some feedback for what I'm doing wrong. Be nice! I'm totally new at this lol

```
 import java.util.Scanner; 
    public class MadLib 
    { 
     private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What is your name >");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your favourite colour >");
        String colour = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Name an animal >");
        String animal = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Give a number >");
        int nm = in.nextInt();

        madlib(name);
    }

    public static void madlib(String name) {
        System.out.print("Hi, my name is " + name + "!");
        System.out.print("Let me tell you a story, one day I was walking down the street,");
        System.out.print("and I saw a wild " + animal + " on the sidewalk! It was a very odd shade of " + colour + ".");
        System.out.print("It was scary!!");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Does it really say "whatever" ? Accurate error messages can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the variables `animal` and `colour` within the `madlib` method, but they are not visible within that scope. You could pass them as parameters:

```
public static void madlib (String name, String animal, String colour) 
{ 
System.out.print ("Hi, my name is " + name + "!"); 
System.out.print ("Let me tell you a story, one day I was walking down the street,"); 
System.out.print ("and I saw a wild " + animal + " on the sidewalk! It was a very odd shade of " + colour + "."); 
System.out.print ("It was scary!!"); 
}
```

Then change the method call in main to this:

```
madlib (name, animal, colour);
```

Comment: +1. And the Scanner can be a local variable in `main`.

Comment: Thanks!! I just realized that actually. Silly mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

In the `madlib` method, you're referencing variables that *don't exist* in the context of the method. They may exist in the `main` method, but those are local variables, and not are visible outside of the `main` method.

The simplest fix is to pass the necessary variables as parameters to the `madlib` method:

```
public static void madlib(String name, String animal, String colour) {
    ...
}
```

And then call the method like so:

```
madlib(name, animal, color);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in scoping. The variable animal & colour is in the scope of the method main and therefore not visible to anything outside the main method. So your reference to animal & colour in the method MadLib causes the error.

The solution is to make the variables class variables or to pass them to the method MadLib like you have done with name.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should be declared in the class, not the main method so that all methods will have access to them. Look up variable scopes in Google. For example this will work

```
     import java.util.Scanner; 
public class MadLib 
{    
      String name, colour, animal;
 private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What is your name >");
    name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your favourite colour >");
     colour = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Name an animal >");
     animal = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Give a number >");
    int nm = in.nextInt();

    madlib();
}
     //You don't necessarily need add a parameter, since this method
     //can now access all of the variables from the class 
public static void madlib() {
    //Use System.out.println() so that each sentence is in its own new line
    System.out.println("Hi, my name is " + name + "!");
    System.out.println("Let me tell you a story, one day I was walking down the street,");
    System.out.println("and I saw a wild " + animal + " on the sidewalk! It was a very odd shade of " + colour + ".");
    System.out.println("It was scary!!");
}
}
```